# Dollar and colon in drools

Tags: java, drools

I am trying to understand drools but I don't find what the dollar and the colon stands for. Can you help?

```
package com.company.license

rule "Is of valid age"
when
    $a : Applicant( age < 18 )
then
    $a.setValid( false );
end
```

Answer (score 4):

Colon is used to bind a variable to a value. It is usually used in 2 places:

1. To bind a whole fact: `$a: Applicant()`
2. To bind a field of a fact: `Applicant($age: age)`

Variables can be then used in the RHS of the rules.

The dollar sign is just a convention to name variables in drools. You don't have to follow this convention if you don't want to. Drools has the same requirements as Java for variable naming.

Hope it helps,

Answer (score 0):

$a = variable.

Colon defines type of the variable.